# How to check if a bot is verified by Discord Bot Verification

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Discord bots can have a [Verified check mark](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412-Bot-Verification-and-Data-Whitelisting). Is there a way to check if a Discord bot is verified using Discord.js?

[image: The first bot is not verified, second is]

I'm doing this mainly to avoid raids or nuke bots

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
   if (member.user.bot) {
      // if is verified:
      //   member.roles.add("<BOT_ROLE_ID>")
      // else:
      //   member.ban(...)
   }
})
```

And if it can't be done using Discord.js, then is there another way using the `member.user.id` property or something else?

Update: [user flags](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object-user-flags) may be the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [`User#flags`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=flags) property as you mentioned in your update. The [available flags](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserFlags?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) can be found in the documentation. You'll need to check if the user has the `VERIFIED_BOT` flag.

```js
if (member.user.flags.has('VERIFIED_BOT')) {...}
```

Or you can import `UserFlags` enums and use [`UserFlags.VerifiedBot`](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/UserFlags#VerifiedBot):

```js
const { UserFlags } = require('discord.js')
// ...
if (member.user.flags.has(UserFlags.VerifiedBot)) {...}
```

Comment: I didn't know Discord.js had those methods, I was about to mess with bit shifting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
   if (member.user.bot) {
      if is member.user.verified:
         member.roles.add("<BOT_ROLE_ID>")
      else:
         member.ban(...)
   }
})
```

I am not sure but this should work.

For more you can visit: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=verified

Comment: `if is member.user.verified:` is not JavaScript. Anyway, I also wanted to answer this but I'm not sure if it's correct as `ClientUser` represents the logged in client's Discord user and probably `member.user` is not a `ClientUser`. It would be great if someone tested this :)

Comment: This wont work . The Discord developer documentation says that `verified` indicates whether the **user's email** is verified or not, see [User Object structure](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object-user-structure). I updated the question with the possible answer